# Wake On LAN behaviour - works intermittently

Tags: wake-on-lan

When I send WoL packets over my network the specified boxes tend to wake up the first time I send the packet each day, but if I turn the box off then subsequent WoL packets tend to be unsuccessful.

Is Wake on LAN designed to have a "cool-off" period or something? Or is there another reason for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rick, I suspect it's to do with the sleep state: you know, [S1, S2, S3, S4, S5](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb693821.aspx).

Maybe your computer is in S3 at the beginning of the day but then you turn it off to S5? I think some computers can wake from S5 but others cannot.

Answer (score 1):

That is because the software you are using is not sending a "subnet directed broadcast"

When your computer is shut down it's ip address will remain in the arp cache for a while but will be removed at some stage. Try different software that you know will work with subnet directed broadcasts.

Comment: That's wrong on so many levels.

Comment: Care to explain any one of those levels ?

Comment: 4 years and still no explanation from "John" which is perhaps why new people don't like posting here with people like John. And yes I still think it was technically a very good answer.